# Cocos2d - how to load 740 sprites without decreasing fps

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I need to load matrix of sprites (32x23) at the start of game, but it decreases FPS to 15! I have no idea how to do it, I tried to do it in this way:

```
 [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"tereni.plist"];
CCSpriteBatchNode *batch = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"tereni.png"];

for(int i = 0; i < 23; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<32; j++)
    {
        CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"1.png"];
        sprite.position=ccp(j*32+32, i*32+32);
        [batch addChild:sprite];    
    }
}
[self addChild:batch];
```

But still the same. 1.png is 32x32 pixels image.

Comment: fps measured on which device? why not use a tilemap?

Comment: ipad simulator... and without this function (Drawing background) it runs on 55 fps

Comment: Is anyone besides yourself going to play your app on the Simulator? It's a rhetorical question … run it on a device and you'll be like WTF?!?

Comment: i understand that it should work better on a real device, but i'm asking is my method for adding sprites ok?

Comment: It is, see my answer. Expect 60 fps on the device, or at least well above 30.

Answer (score 0):

Your method for adding the sprites is fine, but your performance result is invalid.

iOS Simulator has much faster CPU, much more RAM than a device, but incredibly slow rendering. It can not be compared to real device performance. The Simulator doesn't use hardware acceleration, it's a software renderer. Simulator performance is all but irrelevant.

I'm on a quadcore 2012 iMac with the faster GPU, and I even with that machine I get only 30 fps on iPad Simulator in a reasonably complex scene (tilemap, 4 layers). In fact Simulator performance doesn't seem to have improved much between this machine and my previous late 2009 iMac.

Comment: I dont have iPad. I only have iPhone 3G and 4S, and if I test app on, for example, iphone 4s, will it be OK on the ipad too?

Comment: More or less, roughly. Though it's hard to compare.